# Getting a Focusrite 18i20 how do I install with good studio program

Tags: 14.04, sound, video-editor

I'm pretty stoked my new Focusrite 18i20 is at the PO ready to pick up.  What is a great professional audio recording software for ubuntu 14.04?  What do I need to do to make it work?  looking for a great video editing program which will support avchd HD 1080P.
Thanks,
Franklin

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for gratis software or can it be commercial?

For DAWs, Reaper works well with Wine and has a very fair pricing model. The software is of extremely high quality and the standard plugins are on a professional level.

Other users like Ardour, which is free, but I think does not have VST support.

As for NLEs, Kdenlive worked extremely well for me so far, it supports resolutions up to 4K out of the box and has a feature allowing you to edit huge files in lower resolutions to increase live rendering.

Make sure to set up your interface properly. I recommend Jack/Cadence from the KXStudio repositories. They also have guides on how to measure hardware latency and Wine-rt/WineASIO packages, should you want to install Reaper. A realtime kernel is also helpful. The Ubuntu Studio / KXStudio derivatives offer a good setup right away.